# Match the codeigniter default encrypted password in postgresql?

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, encryption, aes

I did not know much about the encryption so pardon my lake of knowledge. I have used the codeigniter default library for the encryption. In this library it is stated

> By default, the Encryption Library will use the AES-128 cipher in CBC mode, using your configured encryption_key and SHA512 HMAC authentication.

In the config file i have set a key for this encryption. Till now i have successfully registered a new user. but now for the login i have to match the password. I want to know how can i achieve this using postgresql? i have seen md5 articles but not AES encryption.

Moreover what is the correct way of doing this either checking the username and encrypted password both or fetching the password, decrypting it and then matching it with the inserted password?

**P.S:** For negative voting don't forget to leave the comment :) 
cheers!

Comment: Don't try to do this. Hashing and encryption are different things. Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: @Narf so what you suggest. Can you plz elaborate

Comment: I literally told you the 2 functions you need to use ... One for hashing passwords, and the other for verifying the hashes. There's nothing to elaborate.

Comment: okay i will search about it. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you carefully read the documentation of [CodeIgniter's Encryption Library](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html), you will find that it clearly states that it should not be used for password storage:

> DO NOT use this or any other encryption library for user password storage! Passwords must be hashed instead, and you should do that via PHP’s own Password Hashing extension.

[PHP's own Password Hashing extension](https://secure.php.net/password) contains the two functions Narf mentioned in his comment: `password_hash()` & `password_verify()`.

For more info you can check the examples from here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: yeah i have read it. i think it is better to use the md5 in the php side. Encryption is good but in this way i have to deal with more with the password matching.